# How to upgrade PHP-FPM to PHP 5.5 on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu

Now that `PHP 5.5.0` is stable, is it possible to update `PHP-FPM` to use `5.5.0`? I use Nginx as my web sever on Ubuntu.

Comment: `FHM`? Didn't you mean `FPM`?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225519/how-to-install-php-5-5-as-its-new-and-has-no-official-packages-yet-on-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to give up packages and build from source, you can have whatever version of PHP you want.  Here're my notes for building PHP 5.5.0.

https://github.com/triplepoint/web_development_vm_how_to/blob/master/docs/php_nginx_vm.md#install-php

Be aware, it's a serious tradeoff of convenience to go this route.  In the long run, I can't say I'd recommend building from source for anything other than a testing environment, but if you're just trying to test out the new features of 5.5, or if you're running a small server and don't mind maintaining it by hand, source is an option.

Answer (score 4):

There is official ppa: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5

Use ppa instead installing from sources.